# class without instance data, or namespace + globals in a sub-namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, global-variables, static-methods, idioms

I have a few related methods, all of which use some global data (*), and all of which are to be implemented in a header. Should I...

- place the methods in a class as static methods, with no instance data members, and the global variable(s) as a static class members?
- place the methods in a namespace, and the global variable(s) in a ::detail sub-namespace?

Both of these options seem a bit ugly to me, but I'm wondering whether one of them has methodical benefits I'm missing, which should make me prefer it. I could try to bend-over-backwards and move the mutex into a .cpp file, so that might be a third option but it'll not be pretty...

---

<sub>(*) - in my specific case it's a mutex.</sub>

Comment: After your last edition, my question is: Why you want them static?

Comment: ... because they need to be global, one-per-process.

Comment: Edited my answer. I hope this time it goes closer to what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only added bonus of using a class here, is that that compiler can complain if anyone ever reaches for that mutex (if you make it private, of course).

But, in both cases, you can only declare the data in the header, and you must still define it only once in some translation unit. I'd recommend you dispense with the *in-header* implementation, and hide the static mutex along with function implementation in the same translation unit.

From that point on, you can use a namespace, since it becomes a matter of organization only.

Answer (score 0):

From a general "good practice" perspective, I would avoid any global data, and use static data as less as possible ( avoid the singleton syndrome ).

The first question is: Does it hurt to have several copy of those objects? Usually, if you are not managing hardware access or similar, it does not. Even if you are supposed to use only one, it is good to make it as general as possible and allows several instance of the class.

Also, static / global variables tend to carry issues with threads/processes, as it is some times difficult to figure how many copy of the static object you have.

So as a short answer: Put them in a class, as non-static, and put those "global" data into the class also.

If the reason to make those data is due to multiple threads or processes, then probably something is wrong at a design point of view.

If you do not have choice over a more appropriate solution, then I would use the namespace: a class using global parameters would break the encapsulation principle which any programmer would expect from your code.

EDITED:

After the edition in the question and trying to get closer of what the question is:

Supposing you require a wrapper around a mutex, which is unique per process.

```
class MyMutexWrapper // very minimal class, you should finish it.
{
    MyMutex mutex;
public:
    anyFunction();
};
```

Once you have this, you may create a single global instance of it and share it through the whole code. A better solution still to create it in any scope and pass it to any component that make use if it.
You could for example pass a reference.

This approach could seem more complex, but it avoid cross dependencies and make your code structure cleaner => you could then reuse it, extend it, maintain it...

Comment: @StoryTeller: yes I did, did you? He speak about "some global data(*)" which could mean several and probably not only mutex. Whenever a mutex is global by design is also very questionable and implementation dependent.

Comment: Yours is not a bad suggestion generally, but I'm in a case where the exceptions do apply, which is why I need globals, hence my question. As for your last paragraph - aren't you essentially saying that using static class members is forbidden?

Comment: @einpoklum: I would say it in a different way: static class functions should not access any out of the class global variable.

Comment: @AdrianMaire: Oh, but I never thought of doing that... maybe my wording wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I don't see how pretending there can be many instances of this class, then preventing their instantiation, makes the code cleaner. Again it seems you could argue the same about any static data members in any class, not just for a mutex.